# Multiple Siddhi apps or one big one

Tags: complex-event-processing, siddhi

We are building an application on top of Siddhi (using the Java library) that allows users to dynamically add rules and have all incoming information going forward be run against those rules. My question is if it's better to have one large app with many queries, streams, windows, and partitions, or to break up each query into it's own application.

We have been including everything in one single Siddhi app (`SiddhiAppRuntime`), but this is starting to become large and I fear things may start interacting with each other in unintended ways. We are also snapshotting the `SiddhiAppRuntime` and restoring state whenever our application gets restarted. This could likely lead to massive restores if we have hundreds of pattern queries to re-run.

I am considering making a separate `SiddhiAppRuntime` from a single `SiddhiManager` for each query. The benefits (as I see them) would be reduce the risk of unintentional interactions, make each query able to function on its own, and restoring the query after a shutdown should be much simpler since it will only need to restore a single query. Potential downsides could be increased overhead for having potentially hundreds of `SiddhiAppRuntime`s.

What is considered best practice for our scenario? What will offer better performance, both for running data through the rules and for restoring the rules in the case we have to restart.

(If this is too broad or any clarification is needed I will do my best to update this question accordingly)

Answer (score 1):

From the lengthy description that you have given I assume these rules that users add does not interact with each other meaning rules add by user1 will not be interacting with rules added by user2.

In such a case it is recommended to use different Siddhi Apps(SiddhiAppRuntimes) for each user. This wont add much additional performance overhead as apps wont be interacting with each other. This will improve snapshoting process as we will be taking separate snapshopts per each app.
Also this will make sure you will have clear separation between each collection of rules and will be easily manageable.